# Query builder output for a report is undefined for a Google Cloud SQL DB but working out fine on ClearBD on Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to generate a csv report which is later mailed to the recipient. The CSV is generated by using `node-query` builder ORM. The resulting CSV is perfectly generated in an environment with my server on Heroku+ClearDB SQL but fails with the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The code portion is as follows:

```
db.qb.order_by('school_order.school_id', 'desc').distinct()
     .select_avg('school_order.student_quality_price', 'average_price')
     .select('student_quality.student_quality_name, school_order.unit, school_order.marks_percent,' + 
             'school_order.fee_amount, school_order.total_marks, school_order.total_value, school_order.po_created_at')
     .where({ 'school_order.student_quality_id': matArray, 'school_order.teacher_id': supArray })
     .from('school_order')
     .join('student_quality', 'school_order.student_quality_id=student_quality.student_quality_id')
     .join('supplier', 'supplier.teacher_id=school_order.teacher_id').group_by(' student_quality.student_quality_name').get(function (err, poRes) {

          var outputpo = []

          console.log("PORESS" + poRes)

          if (poRes.length > 0) {
              poRes.forEach(po => {
              var poDate = new Date(po.po_created_at.toLocaleString()).getTime();
          if (poDate >= startDate.getTime() && poDate <= endDate.getTime()) {
              outputpo.push(po);
          }
    });

}
```

**EDIT**
Database Connection

```
var db_settings = {
    user: `user`,
    password: `password`,
    database: `database`,
    port:port#,

    socketPath: `INSTANCE_STRING`
};
var qb = require('node-querybuilder').QueryBuilder(db_settings, 'mysql', 'single');
module.exports.qb = qb;
```

`qb`  here is the querybuilder variable. In my logs, `console.log("PORESS" + poRes)` returns "PORESSUndefined".

Comment: How are you creating the connection? do you have logs of the connection getting created and the query? do you see the execution of the query on the database side? where are you running the code?

Comment: Are you running this code locally or in a google cloud platform instance?  and Cloud SQL generates logs when the connections are made, could you verify this?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**
The issue was with the GROUP BY clause which some SQL versions make mandatory to include aggregated columns post the `GROUP BY` clause. More details here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html